# Image size on Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, image-manipulation

How to get Image size in Objective-C.

I loaded one image using imagePicker, I want know the size of that image. (w*h)

is it possible?

***Thanks & regards...***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You implement the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069) and in particular the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method. The last parameter in that method is a dictionary that includes an UImage references by the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key. Get this UIImage* and get it's `size` property.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *image = (UIImage*) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //access width and height like this
    image.size.width;
    image.size.height;
}
```